# Не могу подключиться к Bluetooth устройству

Tags: java, android

При попытки соединиться каждый раз выпадает ошибка. С чем может быть связана эта ошибка? Сразу могу сказать что девайс включен и работает. Возможно проблема в том что метод для подключения к bluetooth вызывается из нативной части? То есть логика действий приблизительно такая. Запускаем приложение, нажимаем кнопочку, начинаются выполняться различные действия(включая вызов нативных методов) и в какой-то момент вызывается мой метод с подключением к bluetooth(вызывается он из нативной части). И каждый раз ловлю такую ошибку. Хотя если просто подключиться из activity то все норм подключается.

```
BluetoothSocket socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
socket.connect(); - ПАДАЕТ ТУТ


W/System.err: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
```

Класс подключения.

```
public class BluetoothConnector {

private static final String TAG = BluetoothConnector.class.getSimpleName();

private BluetoothSocketWrapper bluetoothSocket;
private BluetoothDevice device;
private boolean secure;
private BluetoothAdapter adapter;
private List<UUID> uuidCandidates;
private int candidate;

public BluetoothConnector(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure, BluetoothAdapter adapter, List<UUID> uuidCandidates) {
    this.device = device;
    this.secure = secure;
    this.adapter = adapter;
    this.uuidCandidates = uuidCandidates;
    if (this.uuidCandidates == null || this.uuidCandidates.isEmpty()) {
        this.uuidCandidates = new ArrayList<>();
        this.uuidCandidates.add(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
    }
}

public BluetoothSocketWrapper connect() throws IOException {
    boolean success = false;
    while (selectSocket()) {
        adapter.cancelDiscovery();
        try {
            bluetoothSocket.connect();
            success = true;
            break;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                bluetoothSocket = new FallbackBluetoothSocket(bluetoothSocket.getUnderlyingSocket());
                Thread.sleep(500);
                bluetoothSocket.connect();
                success = true;
                break;
            } catch (IOException | FallbackException | InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    if (!success) throw new IOException("Could not connect to device: " + device.getAddress());
    return bluetoothSocket;
}

private boolean selectSocket() throws IOException {
    if (candidate >= uuidCandidates.size()) return false;
    BluetoothSocket tmp;
    UUID uuid = uuidCandidates.get(candidate++);
    if (secure) {
        tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
    } else {
        tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
    }
    bluetoothSocket = new NativeBluetoothSocket(tmp);
    return true;
}

public interface BluetoothSocketWrapper {

    InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException;

    OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException;

    String getRemoteDeviceName();

    void connect() throws IOException;

    String getRemoteDeviceAddress();

    void close() throws IOException;

    BluetoothSocket getUnderlyingSocket();

}

public static class NativeBluetoothSocket implements BluetoothSocketWrapper {

    private BluetoothSocket socket;

    public NativeBluetoothSocket(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return socket.getInputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        return socket.getOutputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public String getRemoteDeviceName() {
        return socket.getRemoteDevice().getName();
    }

    @Override
    public void connect() throws IOException {
        socket.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public String getRemoteDeviceAddress() {
        return socket.getRemoteDevice().getAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        socket.close();
    }

    @Override
    public BluetoothSocket getUnderlyingSocket() {
        return socket;
    }

}

public class FallbackBluetoothSocket extends NativeBluetoothSocket {

    private BluetoothSocket fallbackSocket;

    public FallbackBluetoothSocket(BluetoothSocket socket) throws FallbackException {
        super(socket);
        try {
            Class<?> clazz = socket.getRemoteDevice().getClass();
            Class<?>[] paramTypes = new Class<?>[]{Integer.TYPE};
            Method m = clazz.getMethod("createRfcommSocket", paramTypes);
            Object[] params = new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(1)};
            fallbackSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(socket.getRemoteDevice(), params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new FallbackException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return fallbackSocket.getInputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        return fallbackSocket.getOutputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public void connect() throws IOException {
        fallbackSocket.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        fallbackSocket.close();
    }

}

public static class FallbackException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public FallbackException(Exception e) {
        super(e);
    }

}
```

}